# Open Cart Header position error

Tags: php, variables, opencart

I have been trying to add a position to my header in opencart i would like to put a banner in there ok. so here is what i have done so far.

I opened the language file for banner module here /admin/language/english/module/ entered the following code

```
$_['text_headerbanner']       = 'headerbanner';
```

Next i opened the banner module admin template at /admin/view/template/module/  and added the following code.

```
<?php if ($module['position'] == 'headerbanner') { ?>
<option value="headerbanner" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_headerbanner; ?>       </option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="headerbanner"><?php echo $text_headerbanner; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

And also added to the javascript section round line 140

```
  html += '      <option value="headerbanner"><?php echo $text_headerbanner; ?></option>';
```

And then opened the modules controller file here /admin/controller/module/ and entered

```
$this->data['text_headerbanner'] = $this->language->get('text_headerbanner');
```

That enabled me to assign a newly created banner to the position "headerbanner" in my admin side.

now i went on to adding the position to the template and i fear this is where all went wonky

so i navigated to /catalog/controller/common/home.php
and added

```
'common/content_middle',
```

as the second last array item hence the comma at the end.
then i created a .php file with the name "headerbanner.php" in /catalog/controller/common/ with the following code in it -

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonheaderbanner extends Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('design/layout');
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');
    $this->load->model('catalog/product');
    $this->load->model('catalog/information');

    if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
        $route = $this->request->get['route'];
    } else {
        $route = 'common/home';
    }

    $layout_id = 0;

    if (substr($route, 0, 16) == 'product/category' && isset($this->request- >get['path'])) {
        $path = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

        $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryLayoutId(end($path));
    }

    if (substr($route, 0, 15) == 'product/product' && isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
        $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductLayoutId($this->request->get['product_id']);
    }

    if (substr($route, 0, 23) == 'information/information' && isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
        $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformationLayoutId($this->request->get['information_id']);
    }

    if (!$layout_id) {
        $layout_id = $this->model_design_layout->getLayout($route);
    }

    if (!$layout_id) {
        $layout_id = $this->config->get('config_layout_id');
    }

    $module_data = array();

    $this->load->model('setting/extension');

    $extensions = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('module');

    foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
        $modules = $this->config->get($extension['code'] . '_module');

        if ($modules) {
            foreach ($modules as $module) {
                if ($module['layout_id'] == $layout_id && $module['position'] == 'headerbanner' && $module['status']) {
                    $module_data[] = array(
                        'code'       => $extension['code'],
                        'setting'    => $module,
                        'sort_order' => $module['sort_order']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $sort_order = array();

    foreach ($module_data as $key => $value) {
        $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
    }

    array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $module_data);

    $this->data['modules'] = array();

    foreach ($module_data as $module) {
        $module = $this->getChild('module/' . $module['code'], $module['setting']);

        if ($module) {
            $this->data['modules'][] = $module;
        }
    }

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/headerbanner.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/headerbanner.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/common/headerbanner.tpl';
    }

    $this->render();
}
}
?>
```

and so i carried on to create the corresponding headerbanner.tpl file for this code in /view/theme/beautyshop/template/common/ with this code in it -

```
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
<?php echo $module; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And proceeded to call it in my beautyshop header template with -

```
<?php echo $headerbanner; ?>
```

And i receive this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: headerbanner in /home/demodeto/public_html/catalog/view/theme/beautyshop/template/common/header.tpl on line 702
```

the code for header.tpl is 1000 lines long but here is the basic snippet of the position being called

```
?>
<?php echo $headerbanner; ?>
<div id="menu" class="clearfix">
<?
// custom block
if(($this->config->get('beauty_status') == '1')&&($this->config-     >get('beauty_layout_custommenu_block') == 1)&&($this->config-   >get('beauty_layout_custommenu_block_position') == 0))
{

if($this->config->get('beauty_layout_custommenu_block_title')<>'') echo '<li class="li-    custom-block"><a>'.$this->config->get('beauty_layout_custommenu_block_title').'</a><div    class="custom-topmenu-block"><ul><li>'.html_entity_decode($this->config-   >get('beauty_layout_custommenu_block_content')).'</li></ul></div></li><li    class="separator"></li>';

}
?>
```

I Dont know enough about PHP to debug where this code is trying to define the variable any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easy: You are missing the child for `header` controller:

In `catalog/controller/common/header.php` almost at the end find this array:

```
    $this->children = array(
        'module/language',
        'module/currency',
        'module/cart'
    );
```

Now You would have to add Your new child:

```
    $this->children = array(
        'module/language',
        'module/currency',
        'module/cart',
        'common/headerbanner'
    );
```

This should do the job.